# Call JS on page or element load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the code below which, when I hover over this element "logo p" changes the colors of each character in that element, so each character has a random color.

How should I go about to make this script run on page load. So when the page, or that specific element loads, the code below is executed. I want to have each character with random color, not only on hover but through all time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // COLOURS ARRAY
    var colours = Array("#B0171F", "#FF3E96", "#FF00FF", "#8B008B", "#9400D3", "#BF3EFF",     "#B22222", "#FF0000", "#800000", "#8E388E", "#bc8f8f"), idx;
    $("#logo p").hover(function(){
        var header = $(this); 
        var characters = header.text().split('');
        header.empty();  
        var content = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
            idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
            content += '<span style="color:'+colours[idx]+'">' + characters[i] + '</span>'; 
        }
        header.append(content);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('span').contents().unwrap();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `hover` use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and on the page load just trigger the `mouseenter` event on `target` elements, like, `.trigger('mouseenter');`, so
you may try this

```
$(function(){
    var colours = Array( "#B0171F", "#FF3E96", "#FF00FF", "#8B008B", "#9400D3", "#BF3EFF", "#B22222", "#FF0000",          "#800000", "#8E388E", "#bc8f8f" );
    $("#logo p").on('mouseenter', function(){
        var header = $(this), characters = (header.text()).split(''), content = '';
        header.empty();  
        for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
            var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
            content += '<span style="color:'+colours[idx]+'">' + characters[i] + '</span>'; 
        }
        header.append(content);
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).find('span').contents().unwrap();
    }).trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/uGz6H/3/)

This will work on page load and also on `hover(mouseenter/mouseleave)` and don't need separate handlers for `load` and `hover`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.each`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// COLOURS ARRAY
var colours = Array("#B0171F", "#FF3E96", "#FF00FF", "#8B008B", "#9400D3", "#BF3EFF",     "#B22222", "#FF0000", "#800000", "#8E388E", "#bc8f8f"), idx;
$("#logo p").each(function(){
    var header = $(this); 
    var characters = header.text().split('');
    header.empty();  
    var content = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
        content += '<span style="color:'+colours[idx]+'">' + characters[i] + '</span>'; 
    }
    header.append(content);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('span').contents().unwrap();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a function and call on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function changeElements() {
        // COLOURS ARRAY
        var colours = Array("#B0171F", "#FF3E96", "#FF00FF", "#8B008B", "#9400D3", "#BF3EFF", "#B22222", "#FF0000", "#800000", "#8E388E", "#bc8f8f"),
            idx;
        $("#logo p").each(function(){
            var header = $(this);
            var characters = header.text().split('');
            header.empty();
            var content = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
                idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
                content += '<span style="color:' + colours[idx] + '">' + characters[i] + '</span>';
            }
            header.append(content);
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('span').contents().unwrap();
        });
    }
    changeElements();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be i don't understand the question but you could simply execute your code on documnet ready:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var colours = Array("#B0171F", "#FF3E96", "#FF00FF", "#8B008B", "#9400D3", "#BF3EFF","#B22222", "#FF0000", "#800000", "#8E388E", "#bc8f8f"), idx;
    var header = $("#logo p");
    var characters = header.text().split('');
    header.empty();  
    var content = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
        content += '<span style="color:'+colours[idx]+'">' + characters[i] + '</span>'; 
    }
    header.append(content);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h39LT/)

If you want it to switch colors all the time you could place your code in setInterval

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h39LT/1/) for that.